# How turn off the Synaptic video tutorial after clicking on the touchpad?

Tags: synaptics-touchpad

I installed the new Synaptic driver. There is a video tutorial popping up every time I touch it with my finger.

I read that I could fix it by deleting this videos from Synaptic workspace, but I cannot find any other solution.

How can I turn it off?

Comment: +1 "stupid synaptic video tutorial", I would look in the synaptic tab of mouse properties, there should be a disable setting in there.

Comment: @Moab You +1 people just for ranting? ;)

Comment: @slhck What can I say it caught my attention and made me laugh. Actually it was for showing research effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable SyncNoButtons.wmv](https://superuser.com/questions/498164/how-can-i-disable-syncnobuttons-wmv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My tap zones were set to disabled and I still kept getting the video. What I tried instead was I enabled tap zones and then set all zones to 'No Zone'. So far I have not encountered the video again.

Answer (score 1):

Look under "Tapping", more specifically look at "Tap zones".

I know I had this problem, and one of the touchpad corners was mapped to opening a video. Whenever I touched that corner of the touchpad, the video would pop up.

Try disabling the tap zones or modifying what that specific tap zone does.

Comment: hmm I think I have found solution, but I need some time to check if "it" is the right way :)